# Visual Studio on MAC, MVC EF 7 code first migrations not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations, visual-studio-mac

I recently moved to a MAC M1, installed Visual studio with .NET 7 and I'm running SQL Server in a Docker container and am currently creating an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web app.

I delete the database from SQL Server and delete my migrations folder and add a new migration with nuget package manager console

```
Add-Migration Initial -Context DB
```

Migrations folder is created with my migration.

However, when I run the update the database is created but only with the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table all other tables are ignored.

If I add another migration

```
Add-Migration SecondMigration -Context DB
```

and run the update command all my other tables are then added, with an error that states some of the tables already exist.

If I add a 3rd migration and update the database, EF tries to run the very first migration again, i can see in the `__EFHistory` table the `migrationID` is still the very first migration, it seems every time I run `update-database`, it is using the wrong migration.

Is there a setting I can set or would I need to explicitly specify which migration I need to use when I run `Update-Database` command?

The part that really confuses me is that when the initial migration is added, in the migration class I can see all of the tables that need to be added, but why is only the `__EFHistory` table added.

```
public class DB : DbContext
{
        public DB(DbContextOptions<DB> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasQueryFilter(a=>a.Id != 1);

            foreach (var foreignKey in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
            {
                foreignKey.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.NoAction;
            }
        }

        public  DbSet<ApiRequest> ApiRequest { get; set; }
        public  DbSet<EmailLog> EmailLog { get; set; }
        public  DbSet<NotificationDelivery> NotificationDelivery { get; set; }
        public  DbSet<EmailTemplate> EmailTemplate { get; set; }
        public  DbSet<ErrorLog> ErrorLog { get; set; }
        public  DbSet<GeoLocation> GeoLocation { get; set; }
}
```

DB Table

```
[Table("ApiRequest")]
public class ApiRequest
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Table config

```
public class ApiRequestConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApiRequest>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApiRequest> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        modelBuilder
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        modelBuilder
            .Property(x => x.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        modelBuilder
            .Property(x => x.LastUpdated)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("datetime2(0)");

        modelBuilder
            .Property(x => x.Active)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDefaultValue(true);
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DB>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ClientDatabase"));
});
```

Example of my Migration class

```
public partial class Initial : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
            name: "dbo");

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ApiRequest",
            schema: "dbo",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                LastUpdated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2(0)", nullable: false),
                Active = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false, defaultValue: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ApiRequest", x => x.Id);
            });
     }

      migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "EmailTemplate",
            schema: "dbo",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                Template = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                Placeholders = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(512)", maxLength: 512, nullable: true),
                Active = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false, defaultValue: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_EmailTemplate", x => x.Id);
            });
 }
```

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you use the dotnet ef command line tools? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet

Comment: It does do the same thing for some reason. however the CLI does allow me to specify the migrations name i want to use for the update command. by allowing me to add the name of the migration i want to use it has solved my problem.